# Relationship model in Ruby on Rails tutorial Chapter11.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm not clear with this line in Chapter 11

> Note that, unlike the default generated Relationship model, in this case only the followed_id is accessible.

Why does it happen? Why the follower_id is not accessible?

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code-relationships_belongs_to_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very confusing line of text and I think you should completely ignore its existence.

You absolutely can access `follower_id`. You can also access the associations `follower` and `followed` as per "default generated" rails models. The only difference here is that they will be instances of the `User` class.

Just ignore that line and carry on.